# Adding alternatives to least cloudy image to a collection

Tags: google-earth-engine

I've made a collection of least cloudy images based on the EE tutorial guide, using Landsat 5 data. However, for the area I'm interested in, some of the returned images are not fully covering the area. I'm using the code below:

```
var imageFin1984 = ee.Image(
  l5.filterBounds(ROI)
    .filterDate('1984-07-01', '1984-08-31')
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    .first()
    ).clip(ROI);

var visParams = {bands: ['B3', 'B2', 'B1'], max: 0.3};
Map.addLayer(imageFin1984, visParams, 'True Colour 1984');
```

How would I view the second least cloudy image, or generally improve the coverage of the image for my area?

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar need with Sentinel-2 imagery. If your ROI overlaps more than 1 tile and you sort by cloud cover, it can be difficult to find the second least cloudy image for a particular tile because it could be anywhere in the list depending on the cloud cover for the images covering the other tiles. Instead, you need to identify the tiles within bounds and then use a map() function to find the nth cloudy image for each tile. Here is how I did it for Sentinel-2 imagery:

```
// Load the ROI table
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("users/theronmb/TTCS_Area_Crop_for_Sentinel-2");

// Find the MGRS_TILES that overlap with the ROI for the time period of interest
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(3,6,'month'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2017,2017,'year'))
  .filterBounds(table)
  .distinct('MGRS_TILE')
;

// Get the unique MGRS tile list
var tiles = ee.List(collection.aggregate_array('MGRS_TILE'));

/* Function to iterate through the image collection to pull out the nth 
least cloudy granuales for each target tile.*/
var fun = function(tile) {
  var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(3,6,'month'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2017,2017,'year'))
    .filterMetadata('MGRS_TILE', 'equals', tile)
    .limit(3, 'CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', true);
  var mylist= S2.toList(3);
  var s2 = ee.Image(mylist.get(1)); //change to 2 or 3 for 2nd or 3rd least cloudy
  return s2;
};

// Apply function to tile list
var filtered = tiles.map(fun);

// Create image collection from image list
var filtered = ee.ImageCollection(filtered);

print(filtered)
```